# Why val() value is not working in function?

Tags: javascript

This code is not working. but if inValue in function, it works well.

I want to know why this happens.

```
$('#id').on('input', something);
var inValue = $('#id').val();

function something () {
    console.log(inValue);
}
```

Comment: Most likely your code is executed before the DOM is fully rendered.

Comment: "This code is not working." You should [edit] the question and tell us _how_ it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It is about scope, moving the `val()` inside the function fixes that:

```js
$('#id').on('input', something);

function something () {
    var inValue = $('#id').val();
    console.log(inValue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id" type="text" placeholder="Type in here" />
```

Comment: Thanks^________^ have a nice day!